# Hiding tax amount on one page chceckout using xml file

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, tax, ce-1.8.1.0

I'm trying to hide tax amount on one page checkout. Hiding that in `phtml` files is not a problem, but I want to hide it using `xml` file.

To that moment I have this code in my `local.xml` file:

```
<sales_order_view>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="sales/order_view" name="sales.order.view">
        <block type="sales/order_items" name="order_items" template="sales/order/items.phtml">
            <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
              <action method="unsetChild">
                <name>tax</name>
              </action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </block>
</reference>
</sales_order_view>
```

But it didn't work. Any sugestion?

Comment: So why do you use `sales_order_view` layout handle then?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know which type of layout should I use to this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do it via XML layouts as you can only remove blocks which were previously defined and taxes at the OPC are not separated into a block.

So if you want your products to have taxes but hide them at checkout (which can actually be a legal issue in some countries) you have to modify templates.